# Enum.GetValues(typeof(....)) not returning the proper enum values

Tags: c#, enums

Given this code:

```
public enum Enum1
{
    ONE,
    TWO
}

public enum Enum2
{
    A,
    B
}
```

This code returns ONE, TWO:

```
foreach (Enum1 e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enum1)))
{
  Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

But this code, instead of failing (because `Enum2 e` is used with `typeof(Enum1)`), returns A, B:

```
foreach (Enum2 e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enum1)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because under the covers Enums are just ints - the second returns the values of `Enum1`, but really those values are just `0` and `1`.  When you cast those values to the type `Enum2` these are still valid and correspond to the values "A" and "B".

Comment: Off course they do... Silly me! I forgot that in C# enums are actually fancy ints. I was more used to Java's enums which are full fledged classes. Sad that the compiler doesn't catch it though...

Comment: @JohnDoDo: The compiler does not catch it because "foreach(Enum2 e..." does an **explicit** conversion -- a cast, effectively -- from the collection type to the loop variable type. It is legal to *cast* `(Enum2)enum1`, and so it is legal to do the same thing implicitly with a *foreach*. Remember, foreach was invented before generics; if you had an ArrayList of strings, you'd want to be able to say `foreach(string s in myArrayList)` and have the explicit conversion made automatically.

Answer (score 8):

Because the values of your enums are implicitly integers:

```
public enum Enum1
{
    ONE = 0,
    TWO = 1
}

public enum Enum2
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1
}
```

The values of Enum1 are being implicitly converted to integers and then to values of Enum2.  If you redefined Enum1 as follows...

```
public enum Enum1
{
    ONE = 0,
    TWO = 1,
    THREE = 2,
}
```

...then it would <del>fail</del> not return "A, B", because there is no value in Enum2 for the integer value 2

Comment: Enum values start at 0, and actually that prints `A, B, 2` instead of failing - see [Casting ints to enums in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758321/casting-ints-to-enums-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

When you use `Enum.GetValues()` it returns the underlying values. When you use `foreach(Type...)` it does a cast to the enum type. So, while they may not be the same Enum, they have the same underlying values which have no problem casting.

What is happening in roughly equivalent to this

```
int value = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enum2))[1]; // this isn't valid code, it's more simplified
Enum1 casted = (Enum1)value;
```

Answer (score 2):

`Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enum1))` return {0,1} and `foreach` will enumerate in this range

Answer (score 1):

There is an implicit cast here from Enum1 -> int and int -> Enum2.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess someone like Jon Skeet could come in here and completely explain what is happening better than I am, but this code:

```
foreach (Enum2 e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enum1)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

...is seeing all of your `Enum1` values as `Enum2` types.

Since the `enum` data type is like the `int` data type, your numeric values from `Enum1` are being used to index `Enum2`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that enums are implicitly castable to `System.Int` (assuming they are int  enums, which they are by default).

Your second foreach is then explicitly casting the results of `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enum1))` to `Enum2`.