# Enum not default to 0 when not defined

Tags: c#, enums, default-value

I have an enum type defined as follows:

```
public enum OperationTypeEnum : byte
{
    /// <remarks/>
    @__NONE = 0,

    /// <remarks/>
    Sale = 1,

    /// <remarks/>
    Auth = 2
}
```

In my code, I cast an integer like so:

```
var operationType = (OperationTypeEnum) anotherIntVariable;
```

When anotherIntVariable is something undefined (e.g. 5), I am hoping to get 0 or __NONE back (since 5 is not defined as one of the valid enum values, but I receive 5 instead.

What do I need to change to make undefined enum values to be 0?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that you are the first one to have this problem, and if you search on the internet you will find nothing.

Comment: look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758321/casting-ints-to-enums-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You will need to add validation on top of your enum (e.g. a `GetValue` function or something) - there's nothing built in to do it.

Comment: Don't you think that when you do `var operationType = (OperationTypeEnum) 5;` and use the `switch(operationType)` operation type will end up in `default: `?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov: Yes, but our code is not followed by a switch statement. It's a simple Assert.AreEqual(operationType, anotherVariable) afterward, so unless I write some code to deal with undefined values ahead of time, the Assert will fail. I'll write an extension method to deal with these enum casting statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# enums are effectively integers and there are no compile or run time checks that you are using a "valid" value from your defined enum set. See this answer for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/6413841/1724034

Comment: Looks like I have to write my own extension method to check the integer and default it to 0 if not defined. Thanks!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Thanks! We have a lot of these enum casting in our code, so I was hoping I was just missing something simple, but I suppose not :). I'll write an extension method to deal with all of these undefined enum values.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was given by @plast1k.

Here is a generic extension for your problem

```
public static class OperationTypeEnumExtensions
{
    public static T ToEnum<T>(this byte val) where T : struct
    {
        if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), val)) 
            return (T) Enum.Parse(typeof(T), val.ToString());
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

usage

```
value.ToEnum<OperationTypeEnum>()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This works wonderfully for my problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you get a numerical value and need to only get actual enum values, you can use [Enum.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The example displays the following output:
>   Converted '0' to None.
>   Converted '2' to Green.
>   **8 is not an underlying value of the Colors enumeration.**
>   blue is not a member of the Colors enumeration.
>   Converted 'Blue' to Blue.
>   Yellow is not a member of the Colors enumeration.

```
using System;

[Flags] enum Colors { None=0, Red = 1, Green = 2, Blue = 4 };

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       string[] colorStrings = { "0", "2", "8", "blue", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red, Green" };
       foreach (string colorString in colorStrings)
       {
          Colors colorValue;
          if (Enum.TryParse(colorString, out colorValue))        
             if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Colors), colorValue) | colorValue.ToString().Contains(","))  
                Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", colorString, colorValue.ToString());
             else
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an underlying value of the Colors enumeration.", colorString);
          else
             Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a member of the Colors enumeration.", colorString);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! We have a lot of these enum casting in our code, so I was hoping I was just missing something simple, but I suppose not :). I'll write an extension method to deal with all of these undefined enum values.

Comment: Please, take into account that `Enum.IsDefined` uses Reflection so it's costy.

Answer (score 0):

The safest method is to create an extension method for your enum class that will compare the enum values and if none of them initialize to @__NONE

If you are certain there are only a limited amount of enum values:

```
public static class OperationTypeEnumExtensions
{
    public static OperationTypeEnum ToOperationTypeEnum(this int val)
    {
        switch (val)
        {
            case (int) OperatinTypeEnum.Sale:
                return OperationTypeEnum.Sale;

            cast (int) OperationTypeEnum.Auth:
                return OperationTypeenum.Auth;

             default:
                return OperationTypeEnum.@_none;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int myInt = GetMyIntValue();
OperationTypeEnum myEnum = myInt.ToOperationTypeEnum();
```

Answer (score 0):

#If your enum class is defined as below.

```cs
    public enum CategoryEnum : int
    {
        Undefined = 0,
        IT= 1,
        HR= 2,
        Sales= 3,
        Finance=4
    }
```

Now if you want to find Undefined enum if value doesnot match 1,2,3,4 then using the following **Enum.IsDefine()** function

```cs
Enum.IsDefined(typeof(CategoryEnum), request.CategoryId)

#returns true if id matches any enum values
#else returns false
```

Now for parsing the enum values as string

```cs
public enum Mode
    {
        UNDEFINED = 0,
        APP = 1,
        TEXT = 2,
    }

var value = Enum.TryParse(request.Mode, true, out Mode mode);
#returns mode enum
```

#Now to get Corresponding value for id or vice-vera, have an extension method as below:

```cs
  public static T AsEnum<T>(this string input) where T : struct, IConvertible
        {

            if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
            }

            Enum.TryParse(input, ignoreCase: true, out T result);

            return (T)result;

        }
```

- Then fetch it using **AsEnum() function**:

```cs
var status = searchText.AsEnum<StatusEnum>();
```